# How to do rebase --interactive in a Windows GUI

Tags: windows, git, version-control, git-rebase, git-gui

I have a co-worker who's wedded to the git GUI interface for Windows; I'd like to get him rebasing interactively so he can squash commits.

I've tried using the `Tools->Add` to add `git rebase --interactive` but this just hangs when he tries it. Can the client handle interactive rebases? Is there another GUI client for Windows that can? Or perhaps there is *another way* to squash commits in the client?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to do it through the gui. That said, there are ways to squash commits without the interactive rebase. For instance, one could do a reset --soft 3 commits ago, add everything to the index and commit. This would effectively squash the last 3 commits.